# How to set date from user inputs in android?

Tags: java, android, database, datepicker

I am working on an android project in which I want to get date of birth from the user. I am using a Datepicker in such a way that the Datepicker pop up as a dialog box when I am clicking on button. Now I want to set the selected date to another java.util.date object to save it to database. I tried using setDate(), setMonth methods but its deprecated and throwing null pointer exception.Is there any other efficient method this problem?Attaching my code.

```
private Date dob;
int day,month,year;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        System.out.println("Dob selected="+day+"."+month+"."+year);
        etDOB.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);//setting selected date as Content of edittext 
                                              //(This part is working fine)
        dob.setDate(day);//the following lines throwing null pointer exception
        dob.setMonth(month);
        dob.setYear(year);



    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you're getting the NPE because you never really assigned an instance of Date to your "dob" variable. So at the point where you are trying to set the day/month/year, dob is still null.

As the first line of your OnDateSet callback, just assign a new Date to dob:

```
    dob = new Date();
```

Or even better, you can get the full selected date straight from the DatePicker:

```
    dob = new Date(view.getCalendarView().getDate());
```

Then you don't need these 3 lines:

```
    dob.setDate(day);//the following lines throwing null pointer exception
    dob.setMonth(month);
    dob.setYear(year);
```

I assume you are saving the date into your database as time in milliseconds, so just call getTime() on dob to get it later:

```
    dob.getTime();
```